# Linux command to get connection stats

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I have a long running `sftp` command on my Linux machine uploading files to a remote server. I would like to get some basic connection statistics like time the connection has been on, **total data sent**, **total data received** etc. How can I do this?

Comment: nload is a simple tool that gives you current packets and totals:   sudo apt-get install nload

Comment: This works for total current values. But it can't give you data uploaded / downloaded by a specific process.

Comment: Yes. That is what I interpreted from your question. Another tool you might try (I have not) is iptraf   :    https://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-monitor-network/

Comment: The old ifconfig command can give you a crude indication by showing packets sent and received per interface. If you are handy with iptables you can create iptables rules to match your criteria, then use the -v or -x switch to show the bytes.